# ORA-00904: : invalid identifier - very simple table

Tags: sql

Complete noob, only just figured what a sequence is.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE volunteer_id_seq
    START WITH 1;

CREATE TABLE volunteer (
    volunteer_id VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    title   VARCHAR2(5),
);
```

Returns 4   0.00    CREATE TABLE volunteer_t ( volunteer_id VARCHAR(20) PRIMA   ORA-00904: : invalid identifier -

Comment: You have an extra comma for the second column.

Answer (score 0):

As [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) states in his comment, you have a comma after you declare the second column in your table. Instead, it should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE volunteer (
    volunteer_id VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    title   VARCHAR2(5)
);
```